# Reason for absorbance

Tags: optics, visible-light, waves, wavelength

First quoting the example which raised my curiosity"when light passes through polaroid it absorbs certain direction light rays" 
My question is how this phenomenon of absorbance occurs is this some type of destructive interference?
Any level of answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a polaroid type of polarising material the molecules are aligned in the same direction throughout the sheet when the material is manufactured. Their electric dipoles are therefore also aligned and thus absorb photons whose electric field is parallel with the electric dipoles (to an extent that depends on cos(theta)^2 where theta is the angle between electric dipole and photon polarisation). Photons with a perpendicular polarisation are transmitted. If you use an intense source, such as a laser it is easy to burn a polaroid sheet due to this absorption.